# Patterns for avoiding name-space pollution

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, namespaces, global

[This](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/) article describes a number of patterns to avoid name-space pollution. I listed the patterns below with part of the sample code that was given in the article.

My question is: is there any commonly accepted 'best' way? What are the considerations when choosing one for my project?

**Direct Assignment**

```
var myApp = {}
myApp.id = 0;
myApp.next = function() {
    return myApp.id++;  
}
```

**Using Object Literal Notation**

```
var myApp = {
    id: 0,
    next: function() {
        return this.id++;   
    }
}
```

**The Module Pattern**

```
var myApp = (function() {
    var id= 0;
    return {
        next: function() {
            return id++;    
        },
    };  
})();
```

**Namespace Argument**

```
var myApp = {};
(function(context) { 
    var id = 0;
    context.next = function() {
        return id++;    
    };
 })(myApp);
```

**this as a Namespace Proxy**

```
var myApp = {};
(function() {
    var id = 0;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;    
    };
    this.reset = function() {
        id = 0;     
    }
}).apply(myApp);
```

**The method I currently use**

I used the following method in my own project. Is it bad?

```
function MyObj(){
    this.someProperty = 'something';
}
MyObj.prototype.someFunction = function(){
    this.someProperty =5;
}
myApp = new MyObj();
```

Comment: Well you're creating **two** global symbols instead of one, so if you think that's bad, it's bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no commonly accepted best way.  Sorry.

As Pointy said, your method involves creating the `MyObj` constructor function, which presumably will never be used again, as well as the `myApp` namespace object.  It has at least one other minor disadvantage: you can't prevent yourself or someone else using the code from calling `MyObj` again, which is strange for something that's supposed to be your namespace.

Any of the IIFE-based solution should work fine, and they're mostly interchangeable.  The module (or revealing module) is arguably the simplest.  The namespace argument allows you to break a module over multiple files, something I choose never to do, but if that's what you want, it might be useful.  I can't see any real advantages to the "this as a Namespace Proxy" method.

Comment: I like the namespace argument pattern but I have one question. In the method I used, I could instantiate multiple objects by doing `myObj1 = new MyObj(); myObj2 = new MyObj();` And all of the objects would share the same functions as they were bound to the same prototype object. How would you instantiate multiple objects using the namespace through argument pattern, where each object share the same methods?

Comment: Actually, the whole point is that you wouldn't do so.  A namespace as generally used is singular.  That's really the point.  If you're looking for general object construction patterns, this is not the right list of options.  Then you could do simple prototype work as you mention, use `Object.create`, choose one of the many helper libraries for this, or just [search for](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=javascript+object+creation+patterns) javascript object creation patterns.

Comment: Thanks. I am mixing up two things apparently. So I suppose if you combine them you get this: [link](http://pastebin.com/2cXkSNtz). If you want to re-use a component that does not use the namespace argument pattern then you just remove the namespace before all function and variable references. Seems like a good solution.

Comment: Yes, of course you can use various patterns _within_ your namespace code block(s), including this prototypal OO pattern.